# Algoritmo calculadora polaca y punteros

Tags: c

Tengo un pequeño problema en cuanto a punteros para utilizar el algoritmo de calculadora polaca inversa. Aquí comparto el código:

```
//Dado un arreglo de caracteres que representan las componentes
//de una expresion en notacion polaca inversa, evalua dicha
//expresion.
//Apila los caracteres numericos en una pila, y cuando encuentra un
//operador matematico, desapila los numeros anteriores y ejecuta esa
//operacion. Apila el resultado.
double calculadora_polaca(char** arreglo, size_t m){
    pila_t* pila = pila_crear();
    if(!pila) return 0.0;
    for(size_t i=0; i<m; i++){
        char* actual = arreglo[i];
        if(isdigit(actual)) pila_apilar(pila,actual);
        else if(es_operador(actual)){
            double resultado;
            char operador = obtener_operador(actual);
            double operacion1 = (*((double*)pila_desapilar(pila)));
            double operacion2 = (*((double*)pila_desapilar(pila)));
            switch(operador){
                case '+':
                    resultado = operacion1+operacion2;
                    break;
                case '-':
                    resultado = operacion1-operacion2;
                    break;
                case '*':
                    resultado = operacion1*operacion2;
                    break;
                case '/':
                    resultado = operacion1/operacion2;
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("ERROR: comando desconocido %c\n",operador);
            }
            pila_apilar(pila,&resultado);
        }
    }
    double res_final = (*((double*)pila_desapilar(pila)));
    return res_final;
}

int main(){
    char* arreglo[3] = {'+','4','1'};
    double res =  calculadora_polaca(arreglo,3);
    printf("%f",res);
    return 0;
}
```

El problema lo tengo, creo, que en la funcion `main()`. Al compilar, me muestra el siguiente error.

> ```
> calc-pol-inversa.c:74:22: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
>   char* arreglo[3] = {'+','4','1'};
> ```

3 errores iguales por cada elemento del arreglo. ¿Qué tengo mal?

Answer (score 2):

```
char* arreglo[3] = { '+','4','1' };
```

Con eso, creas un *arreglo* con espacio para 3 punteros a `char`, o, lo que es mas o menos lo mismo, con espacio para 3 punteros a cadenas.

Me parece que lo que quieres haces es una especie de *pila* con valores, para procesarlos. En ese caso:

```
char *arreglo[] = {
  "+",
  "1",
  "4"
};
```

Que crearía un *arreglo* para cadenas. Si solo quieres caracteres individuales, sería

```
char arreglo[] = { '+', '1', '4' };
```

Fíjate en las comillas en los 2 casos: `""` indica *cadena*, mientras que `''` indica caracter.

Igualmente, `char *` es *puntero a cadena*, mientras que `char` es simplemente *un caracter*.

Además, no es necesario que indiques el tamaño. El compilador se da cuenta el solito.